# Where is Waze accurate?

Tags: traffic, mobile-apps

At home I am a huge fan of [Waze](https://www.waze.com/) In my opinion, it is the best and most accurate source of traffic information at home that is. However, recently I used Waze on a trip in San Diego. Only to find that the predicted traffic jams in San Diego from Waze are a joke. At some time the cursor in the Waze app was heading towards a massive junction of red lines, only to learn that I was totally on my own.

Apparently, Waze is only accurate in certain regions. Since the quality of the information given depends on the amount mobile devices in the area, I would expect San Diego to be part of that set of regions. I was proven wrong.

Can you learn before using Waze what its coverage is in a given region? 
If the coverage is bad, does that indicate that other apps will do worse, meaning Waze is still a good source?

Comment: There is a delay between the time something happens and the time it is reflected in Waze, or even Google Maps. It's generally only a couple of minutes at most, but it's possible for a traffic jam to clear entirely in that time.

Comment: The Live Map on the waze website shows all the data that is uploaded and downloaded to devices. Right now it's 0749 in San Diego and there appear to be plenty of wazers about, so I would expect the traffic conditions data to be accurate. Your experience surprises me - I too would have expected San Diego to be somewhere where waze is at its best...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know. but my observations are not based on that example only. It was kind of consistent and compared to my experience in Antwerp, where I consider Waze a crucial lifeline.  To be fair, my experience in San Diego covered a week, which might have been an exceptional slow week. So it would be interesting to hear of contradicting opinions/experiences

Comment: It's a street-by-street thing. Near where I live, at the eastern terminus of a major road, the driver chooses one of three paths, leading to two different bridges over the Potomac, and to a northbound highway. At different times of the day, different lanes will be backed up. If more Wazers are in the emptier lanes, no traffic is reported; if they're in the fuller lanes, then the map turns deep red— and they're both right. As with any tool, Waze is best used in conjunction with local knowledge and patience for the occasional anomaly.